# Tried to synchronously call anonymous function from a different thread using Stack.navigator

Tags: react-native

I had everything working fine, until i implemented the Stack.Navigator; then i got this error
[image]

Here's my stack.navigator:

```
<NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Auth" screenOptions={{headerShown: false}} >
            <Stack.Screen name="Register" component={Register} />
            <Stack.Screen name="ChooseLanguage" component={ChooseLanguage} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
```

Here's my libraries:

```
"@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.17.10",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.13",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.4",
    "jsc-android": "^250230.2.1",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-native": "0.65.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.9.0",
    "react-native-paper": "5.0.0-rc.9",
    "react-native-reanimated": "2.3.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.4.1",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.18.2",
    "react-native-svg": "^13.5.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
    "react-native-web": "^0.15.5"
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure:

```
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
```

and you have ***Register*** screen and ***ChooseLanguage*** screen

Comment: These are available, i have them imported